# Sun Codemodel generic method invocation

Tags: java, generics, method-invocation, sun-codemodel

I'm using Codemodel library for java-class generation. Is there a way to generate a generic method invocation which looks like this:

```
clazz.<String>get(value)
```

There is certainly a way of just casting a return result to a correct type using the following expression:

```
JExpr.cast(stringType, clazz.invoke("get").arg(value))
```

which results in

```
(String) clazz.get(value)
```

but the preferred way of casting is the first one, as this code is generating templates for further manual editing by developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the existing JCodeModel API, there is no pre-built way to handle this.  You can, however, define your own `JStatement` type to generate the generic declaration like this:

```
    JDefinedClass definedClass = codeModel._class(JMod.PUBLIC, "org.test.Tester", ClassType.CLASS);

    JMethod method = definedClass.method(JMod.PUBLIC, codeModel.VOID, "test");

    final JType targetType = codeModel.ref(String.class);
    final JVar clazzVar = method.body().decl(codeModel.ref(Class.class), "clazz", JExpr.invoke("getClass"));

    method.body().add(new JStatement(){
        @Override
        public void state(JFormatter f) {
            f.g(clazzVar).p(".<").g(targetType).p(">").p("get").p("();").nl();
        }
    });
```

Which generates:

```
package org.test;

public class Tester {

    public void test() {
        Class clazz = getClass();
        clazz.<String >get();
    }
}
```

This is by no mean a complete solution (It's missing method call arguments for instance).  Take a look at the implementation of the `generate()` method in `JInvocation` for the details that are required.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks, John!